# How to simplify a lambda method that receives a list of integers and returns a string by adding a letter before the number?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I wanted to simplify this method so that I didn't need an `ArrayList`, that is, that only with lambdas I could stream the list of integers, analyze who is even or odd, add their corresponding letter and concatenate in a string

```
public static String o1e3method(List<Integer> list) {
    List<String> n = new ArrayList<>(); 
    list.forEach(x -> {
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            n.add("e" + x);
        }
        else {
            n.add("o" + x);
        }
    });
    return String.join(", ", n);
}
```

In other words, I wanted something that was something like this:

```
public static String o1e3b(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream()
        .map(Object::toString)
        .forEach(x -> {
            if (Integer.parseInt(x) % 2 == 0) {
                x = "e" + x;
            }
            else {
                x = "o" + x;
            }
        })
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

but I can't do this because the `forEach` is a `void` method and doesn't return what to collect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply `map` to String as:

```
return list.stream()
            .map(x -> x % 2 == 0 ? "e" + x : "o" + x)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: Or `.map(x -> (x % 2 == 0 ? "e" : "o") + x)`

Comment: I hadn’t thought about using ternary, I was blind trying to use the IF conditional, which the map doesn’t accept (without return of course).  thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

`forEach` is a *terminal* operation, which does not return Stream. You need an *intermediate* operation to transform your numbers and return transformed stream, which you will later collect.

Note, that you have a redundant mapping to String, which you simply do not need.

I would recommend:

```
public static String o1e3b(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .map(x -> x % 2 == 0 ? "e" + x : "o" + x)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

Just in case you are not familiar, see what is [Ternary Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html), which I use as a body of the mapper function.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but instead of `forEach`, you should use `map`. Also note there's no reason to convert the integers to string and then parse them again:

```
public static String o1e3b(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .map(x -> {
                if (x %2 == 0) {
                    return "e" + x;
                } else {
                    return "o" + x;
                }
            })
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

Comment: my madness was so bad that I was converting it to a string because I couldn't add the character. thank you very much for showing the use of if with return within a map, because of that my ifs didn't work when I tried something similar.